# Python Distance Formula

Tags: python

This is my first time on stack overflow. I wrote this simple program in Python to solve the distance formula. However when I run this code it says syntax error underlining variable a. Any advice would be deeply appreciated.
Thank You

```
import math


def distance(a,b,c,d):
    print("distance formula solver")
    return(math.sqrt((a-b)**2) + (math.sqrt((c-d)**2))


a = int(input("Enter X1"))
b = int(input("Emter X2"))
c = int(input("Enter Y1"))
d = int(input("Enter Y2"))

e = distance(a,b,c,d)

print(e)
```

Comment: You have unbalanced parentheses.

Comment: `return(math` never gets closed. Makes me feel uneasy just looking at it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your return statement has an extra open parenthesis.  Remove it.

```
return(math.sqrt((a-b)**2) + (math.sqrt((c-d)**2))

return math.sqrt((a-b)**2) + (math.sqrt((c-d)**2))
```

I learned to do this by counting through the line: add 1 for each open paren, subtract one for each close.  You must be at zero at the end of the line, and must not go negative at any point.

```
return(math.sqrt((a-b)**2) + (math.sqrt((c-d)**2))
      1         23   2   1   2         34   3   21 ... oops
```

Comment: If you have any sort of language-friendly text editor, you can put the cursor at one parenthesis, and the other will appear highlighted.

Comment: Also, note that your distance calculation is incorrect.  First you add the squares; then you take the square root of that sum.  There should be only one call to sqrt.

Comment: Not much point answering a question that should be closed for being a typo or trivial error.

Answer (score -1):

Juanchopanza is right, add a parenthesis at the end:

```
return(math.sqrt((a-b)**2) + (math.sqrt((c-d)**2)))
```